# Java pass enum as parameter from a class to another class

Tags: java, enums, parameter-passing

How can I handle pass an enum from a class to another class. The passed enum inits another enum in `Test2` class.

Here is an explanation of my problem. I know enum is final and cannot be override. So figure out the 
`this.Jun2 = E;` The code is just explanation.

```
class Test1{
 enum Junk{A,B,C}; 
 Test2.loader(Junk);

}

class Test2{
 enum Junk2{};
 public static void loader(enum E) 
  this.Junk2 = E;
}
...other jobs based on Junk2;
```

The purpose of, `Test2` class as an abstract class that handle enums which are desingned from extended classes like `Test` class

Comment: `Junk` and `Junk2` are two different types and cannot be assigned to each other. Can you explain a bit more what you are trying to achive, problably there is another solution to your problem. Btw an enum can implement an interface.

Comment: I want to desing an abstract class that handle enums which are desingned from extended classes

Answer (score 2):

You specify the enum type in `loader`'s signature (you'll need to give access to the enum to both classes):

```
 public static void loader(Junk junk)
```

You've shown a second, separate enum in `Test2`. It would probably make more sense for `Test2` to use `Junk` as well, not a separate enum. If you use a separate one, you'll have to have a mapping between the values (which you'd usually implement as a method on the enum, e.g., `Junk2.fromJunk(...)`), which is a maintenance issue.

---

Side note: In the above, I changed the name of the argument from `E` to `junk`. In Java, the *overwhelming* convention is that argument names start with a lower case letter. Separately, the name of the argument should reflect what it is in some way. `E` might suggest "enum," but which one? In general, without going overboard, make names specific enough to be meaningful in some way.